# Will VS2010 Beta 1 upgrade to the final product?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Will VS2010 Beta 1 upgrade to the final product?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not. No other versions have from what I remember.

Answer (score 1):

+1 Agree with workmad3. very very unlikely. As he said, no other version has.

Also, a lot of changes happen during Beta, and in fact, sometimes getting Beta versions off your computer to make way for release versions can be a hassle.