# Will Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 interfere with my Visual Studio 2008 install?

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 Beta side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

I would like to play around with the beta and the new entity framework if possible.

Will VS2010 mess around with my Visual Studio 2008 install?

I still need VS08 for work.

CV

Comment: See this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems

Answer (score 0):

I had them working side by side without any problems (until I upgraded by disk - still have a lot of installs to do). However, I can't say that I have done a thorough test.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any extensive testing, but on my box at home I was running both at the same time with no apparent problems.