# Run VSTS 2010 side by side with VSTS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

I'm planning to install VSTS 2010 Beta 1 in my development workstation and i don't know if my VSTS 2008 will continue working..

Have someone tried this??

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this specific situation, but over many years of experience in the past, it seems that people live to regret installing betas in with other stuff.

It's highly likely that the release versions of the two Visual Studios will co-exist happily.

It's just that betas aren't intended to be bullet-proof. They're intended to be confined to sandboxes. If you don't have the luxury of other machines, could could create a separate partition or virtual machine to install the beta in?

You really don't want to mess up your development workstation and have to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Works for me. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have installed VSTS 2010 side by side with VSTS 2008. I am one of them.

See also this blog talking about [Team Explorer 2010 Beta 1 Compatibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2009/05/18/team-explorer-2010-beta-1-compatibility.aspx)

Also answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

Answer (score 0):

There is always a risk that something goes wrong and don't blame Microsoft then. If you write any production code on your workstation, I would recommend installing it on a virtual machine, especially when it is so easy nowadays.