# Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on one machine

Tags: .net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 Beta side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

Hi,
Do you have any experience in having two different visuals(2008 and 2010) on one computer? I'm not sure if there wont be any problems with framework 4? I still want to develop some apps using 3.5 framework and vs 2008

Thanks

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've installed VS 2010 and VS 2008 on my home PC and so far everything is fine. I haven't run into any issues at all. I've been able to continue with my .NET 3.5 dev projects and have been experimenting with .NET 4.0 projects as well.

Comment: Same here, but I've installed both on my work desktop.

Comment: My concern is that removing/upgrading VS2010 beta2 might be painful, and I don't want to rebuild my entire work desktop. I'll probably do it anyway...

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe - Admittedly I haven't removed it and it's definitely a valid concern considering the history of issues when removing a Microsoft beta product from your PC.

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28VS.100%29.aspx) tells us that you'll not encounter any problems, but your should do the following:

> In general, you should install the
>   earliest release of Visual Studio
>   first, and then install subsequent
>   versions of Visual Studio in the order
>   in which they were released. For
>   example, Visual Studio .NET 2002
>   should be installed before Visual
>   Studio 2005, and Visual Studio 2005
>   should be installed before Visual
>   Studio 2008.

Good luck.

EDIT: There's already a question about it: 
[Will installing Visual Studio 2010 Beta side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems).

Comment: sorry I didn't find this post :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm running both right now without any problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

It works great. I had both on my machine since VS2010 Beta 1. Last week, I reinstalled Windows and switched completely to VS2010 Beta 2. Its multitargeting feature handles 3.5 apps pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem - Microsoft have set out quite explicitly to support side by side installation of 2008 and 2010 (and of multiple versions of the .NET Framework).

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2008 for production work. I have VMware installed and have a vm for all my testing. VMware server is free and will meet all your needs. VMware workstation was less than $100 when I bought my copy and it will make your life a good deal easier. I know this is not exactly the answer you were looking for but it works for me.

Comment: For information, VirtualPC is free and works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible point, while it may work properly, I try to make a point of never (ever) installing beta software on my main work machine.  Create a virtual machine, or have a play machine somewhere, but it's not worth the hassle if there are small problems that are not immediately obvious.