# Can I run VS 2008 and VS 2010 on the same computer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to install VS 2010 RC but do not want to get rid of VS 2008 until the 2010 final release.

Comment: The only problem I have had was the MVC 2 tooling between the two, and if you have Resharper, the preferences may need reset in 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two can be installed side by side. Follow instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 Beta side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the short answer is definitely *yes*.  In general, though, there are some issues with some of the out-of-band installed components that aren't fully side by side compatible.  I'm thinking specifically of the [Silverlight 4 Beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/amyd/archive/2009/10/21/visual-studio-2010-and-silverlight-3-sdk.aspx), which I believe conflicts with the Silverlight 3 tools if they are already on your machine.  Also, if you are doing any [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7aba081a-19b9-44c4-a247-3882c8f749e3&displaylang=en) development, this is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Even with VS2005 and VS2008 and VS2010