# Install Visual Studio 2008 AFTER 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Have a shiny new Windows 7 64-bit machine and got a bit over zealous and installed Visual Studio 2010 before I installed VS 2008.  Still need 2008, can I install 2008 after 2010 or do I need to uninstall 2010, install 2008, then SP1, then reinstall 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will installing Visual Studio 2010 side by side with VS2008 cause problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems)

Comment: I read that post but my question is a little more specific, I know they can co-exist fine. I am concerned about any possible impacts that the order of installation may have given that I will be installing 2008 after 2010.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling VS2010 shouldn't be necessary.  Install VS2008 and SP1, then run the VS2010 uninstaller but choose to repair rather than uninstall, this will fix any registry settings broken by installing in the "wrong" order.

Comment: For this solution, have anyone had any problems with add-ons installed on VS2010? This should also be noted, maybe with some edit in a question.

Comment: I did just what he said and it worked for me, I tried to install SP1 also, but I had problems doing that. Gave me an error every time. Its fine though my projects launch fine without SP1.