# Can I have both VS2008 and VS2010 installed on my PC?

Tags: visual-studio

Can I have both VS2008 and VS2010 installed on my PC?

Comment: turns out this is a duplicate (though phrased differently): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems

Comment: I didn't see the original question but then I appreciate all the GREAT answers.  Thanks SO :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they will work fine side by side.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. I do, with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you need to install 2008 first and then 2010. The most recent version should always be installed last.

Comment: I've had no problems installing VS2010 first. This may have been the case in the past with say 2002 and 2003, but I don't think there's a problem now. Of course, if you want to err on the side of caution, there's no harm in installing in this manner - I just don't think it's mandatory.

Comment: I didn't say there would be issues, but I had a problem with files associations (among other things) when I installed 2005 and 2008 after 2010. You just got lucky :)